# Setting the desktop background on all Spaces in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, desktop

I'm writing a small app to change your desktop background. If the user only uses one space, then it's all fine, but when he has multiple spaces the app only works on the currently active space.

I'm using this code

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:currentImageURL 
                                        forScreen:screenToChange 
                                          options:screenOptions 
                                            error:&error]
```

to change the desktop background, and it looks like there's no way to change the background of another space.

I only found answers from several years ago, and nobody asked this specific question. Is there a way to do it in objective-c?

Comment: I don't know the answer either. I've searched for this myself and haven't been able to make it work consistently in objective-c or applescript. It seems to me that apple just won't expose this ability to developers just like we can't do anything with spaces either.

Comment: @HussainShabbir You're right, but I haven't had time to test this yet, please wait a little bit more, I'm overwhelmed right now

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this was quite some time ago. I couldn't find any way at the time to solve this, but things might have changed by now. Sorry I couldn't provide any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Setting the desktop background on all Spaces in Cocoa
```

If user wants to set the desktop background for multiple spaces then try the below code.:-

For more information [refer this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)

```
NSString* path = @"/Users/abc/Desktop/yourImg.png";

NSUserDefaults* def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary* desktopDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[def persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.desktop"]];
NSMutableDictionary* bgDict = [desktopDict objectForKey:@"Background"];
NSMutableDictionary* spaces = [bgDict objectForKey:@"spaces"];
[spaces enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* key, NSMutableDictionary* obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [obj enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, NSMutableDictionary* prefs, BOOL *stop) {
        [prefs setObject:path forKey:@"ImageFilePath"];
        [prefs setObject:path forKey:@"NewImageFilePath"];
        [prefs setObject:@"Never" forKey:@"Change"];
    }];
}];
[def setPersistentDomain:desktopDict forName:@"com.apple.desktop"];
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 10.11. Trying to get the persistent domain "com.apple.desktop" returns nil. Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

Although there is no public API for changing spaces background there are ways to do it.
The keyword you are looking for is `com.apple.desktop.plist` which is inside `~/Library/Preferences/` That's the plist that stores all the current background for all the current spaces. If you want to use objective-c you can change this file to your liking or you can use one of the suggested solutions [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130307194450/https://arfore.com/2012/07/05/changing-wallpaper-on-all-spaces-in-mac-os-x-10-7/) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98224/changing-the-background-image-in-all-spaces). If you are targeting Mavericks the wallpapers data is here: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db"`

Comment: How do we change `desktoppicture.db`?