# Setting the Desktop background on OSX using Swift 2

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, swift2

After an introduction to Javascript, I'm trying to tackle OSX/iOS programming by creating some simple tools to scratch my own itches.

However, right from the jump I hit a roadblock.

I found two examples that should work.

1. https://github.com/hinderberg/ios-swift-kurs/blob/master/swift-intro/wallpaper.swift
2. https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/196825/Swift-shell-script-to-randomize-wallpape

Here's the second:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

import Foundation
import AppKit
let imagesDir = "/Users/david/Dropbox/Graphics/Wallpaper-HD/"
var err: NSError?

let fs = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let filenames = fs.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(imagesDir, error: &err) as [String]?

if let error = err {
  NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
} else {

  let imagenames = filenames!.filter { $0.hasSuffix(".jpg") || $0.hasSuffix("png") }
  let ir = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imagenames.count)))
  let imgurl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(imagesDir + imagenames[ir])

  let workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
  let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen()
  let ok : Bool = workspace.setDesktopImageURL( imgurl!, forScreen: screen!, options: nil, error: nil )

  if ok { 
    println( "New wallpaper: " + imagenames[ir] ) 
  } else { 
    println("Oops!")
  }
}
```

This didn't work in XCode 7 beta 3.

Hoping to reduce to the essentials, I arrived at:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift
import Foundation
import AppKit
let imagesDir = "/Users/josh/Downloads/"
let singleImage = "/Users/josh/Downloads/xlarge.png"


let imgurl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(singleImage)

let workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen()
let ok : Bool = workspace.setDesktopImageURL( imgurl, forScreen: screen!, options: nil, error: nil )

if ok {
    print( "New wallpaper set!" )
} else {
    print("Oops!")
}
```

And saved as the file `wallpaper.swift`.

On execution, the error is:

```
./wallpaper.swift:17:49: error: extra argument 'error' in call
let ok : Bool = workspace.setDesktopImageURL( imgurl, forScreen: screen!, options: nil, error: nil )
```

And now I'm completely stuck...
I've tried referring to [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW45) and [NSScreen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScreen/visibleFrame) documentation as well as running through playground, but it's beyond my current skills.

Removing the extra argument it complains about (error: nil) simply gives a different error:

```
./wallpaper.swift:13:31: error: cannot invoke 'setDesktopImageURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, forScreen: NSScreen?, options: nil)'
let ok : Bool = workspace.setDesktopImageURL( imgurl, forScreen: screen, options: nil )
```

Where is the code failing, and how can I understand how to make it work properly?

Comment: Not familiar waith OSX functions, but judging from the error, have you tried removing "error: nil" from the "workspace.setDesktopImageURL" function?

Comment: Yes, and the error returned is `./wallpaper3.swift:13:31: error: cannot invoke 'setDesktopImageURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, forScreen: NSScreen?, options: nil)'
    let ok : Bool = workspace.setDesktopImageURL( imgurl, forScreen: screen, options: nil )` . The "extra argument" error seems to be one of those "It's broken, figure it out yourself" errors.

Comment: In Xcode, use ALT+CLICK to see the type of an object. If you do ALT+CLICK on `.setDesktopImageURL`, Xcode will show you the type *and signature* of this method. Then you will see the right parameters you have to use (documentation is probably not updated).

Comment: @EricD. That's handy, thank you. I clicked on `.setDesktopImageURL` and it said no quick help, but when I command-clicked, it took me to the declaration (also handy, wouldn't have thought of that). The code there is `func setDesktopImageURL(url: NSURL, forScreen screen: NSScreen, options: [String : AnyObject]) throws` . Does this make more sense to where the error is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example you're passing `nil` as `options` to the method.

I guess it worked before but now in the comments you showed the current method signature:

```
(url: NSURL, forScreen screen: NSScreen, options: [String : AnyObject]) throws
```

We see that `options` should be a non-Optional Dictionary.

It means you can't use `nil` anymore for the `options` parameter: if you don't have options, just pass an empty Dictionary.

Also, now in Swift 2, this method doesn't return a Bool anymore, it throws.

Meaning you have to use it with `do try catch`:

```
do {
    let imgurl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(singleImage)
    let workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
    if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen()  {
        try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(imgurl, forScreen: screen, options: [:])
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This code worked perfectly, and the explanation is clear.
Thank you.
I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Works like a charm! Any idea how to set the desktop picture on multiple spaces?

Comment: @Hexagons Unfortunately there's no API for that. Some [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586289/setting-the-desktop-background-on-all-spaces-in-cocoa) used to work but apparently not anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Updated example for Swift 3:

```
do {
   let imgurl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: singleImage)
   let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared()
   if let screen = NSScreen.main()  {
       try workspace.setDesktopImageURL(imgurl, for: screen, options: [:])
   }
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated version for Swift 5.x:

```swift
do {
    let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/image")
    if let screen = NSScreen.main {
        try NSWorkspace.shared.setDesktopImageURL(imageURL, for: screen, options: [:])
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of us using Xamarin Mac, this can be achieved like so:

```cs
string filepath = "/Users/you/Desktop/sweet-wallpaper.jpg";

var workspace = NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace;
var screen = NSScreen.MainScreen;

NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromFilename(filepath);
NSDictionary options = new NSDictionary();
NSError errorContainer = new NSError();

workspace.SetDesktopImageUrl(url, NSScreen.MainScreen, options, errorContainer);
```