# Flutter macos change background on button click

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter

at the moment im experimenting with the flutter macos application. Basically I want to create a button in my macos app which sets a background image on my macbook. Creating the button ofcourse is not the problem. I dont know how to "call" my macs background to change on button click. I also dont have any idea on how and furthermore what to research. This is my code...

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Set Background Image to my Mac'),
            onPressed: _setBackgroundImage(),
          ),
          Text(currentBackgroundName),
        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: the background image of what, desktop or some NSView?

Comment: I want to change the background image of my macbook programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31840814/6576315 check this, write the function in swift file and invoke that from flutter side