# Is there a way to set user desktop background wallpaper programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I haven't been able to find much documentation on this except this ([Setting the Desktop background on OSX using Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840147/setting-the-desktop-background-on-osx-using-swift-2))

Is there a way to programmatically set users' desktop wallpaper using Swift on a macOS app? I understand I'll have to disable sandbox for it, but what can I use to programmatically set the desktop wallpaper?

Comment: I can't speak for Apple, but the intention of SwiftUI is for building application user interfaces, not wider OS control, which setting the desktop image is.  As long as it's not a Catalyst app, there's nothing preventing you from using using the Cocoa API in your SwiftUI app.  If you'd prefer a declarative API for doing it, you could always write your own using result builders to wrap the Cocoa API.

Comment: Minor correction to my last comment: As long as it's not a Catalyst app, there's nothing preventing you from using Cocoa in your SwiftUI *macOS* app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your quoted link has the answer. Here is a demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showFileImporter = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Pick Background Image") {
            showFileImporter = true
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $showFileImporter, allowedContentTypes: [.jpeg, .tiff, .png]) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error selecting file \(error.localizedDescription)")
            case .success(let url):
                print("selected url = \(url)")
                setDesktopImage(url: url)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func setDesktopImage(url: URL) {
        do {
            if let screen = NSScreen.main {
                try NSWorkspace.shared.setDesktopImageURL(url, for: screen, options: [:])
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```