# Set desktop background image for all Spaces (possibly using com.apple.desktop)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to change the desktop background image for all of a user's Spaces at the same time. After some research I found [a likely solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586289/setting-the-desktop-background-on-all-spaces-in-cocoa) but it relies on accessing the .plist file named "com.apple.desktop". When I try to access that file using this line of code, its value is `nil`:

```
let desktopDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().persistentDomainForName("com.apple.desktop")
```

Yet, if I try the same thing with another string ie: "com.apple.dock" I get a dictionary as expected. So I know my syntax is right, but it seems that the way to access the com.apple.desktop plist has changed in the past couple years.

Can I still use com.apple.desktop to change the wallpaper for all Spaces at once? Or is there some other way I should be doing this? Thanks.