# Is it possible to (programmatically) set wallpapers for each separate "space"/desktop in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsworkspace, macos-high-sierra

I'm making a small app for myself to change the desktop background image periodically.

My program contains this block of code:

```
let screen = NSScreen.main()!
let newWallpaperURL = URL(/* ... */)
// ...
try! NSWorkspace.shared().setDesktopImageURL(newWallpaperURL, for: screen, options: [:])
```

This works, but only for the current "space" the keyboard is focused on.

e.g. if I'm in a fullscreen app, only the background of the Space occupied fullscreen app will be changed (not the background of my normal desktop).
If I have two Spaces/desktops, it only changes the background image of one of them.

Is it possible to individually set wallpapers for each space programmatically?

Comment: It's been 3 years. Have you found a sollution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the screens and set all of them.

```
let screens = NSScreen.screens
let newWallpaperURL = URL(/* ... */)
for i in screens {
    try! NSWorkspace.shared().setDesktopImageURL(newWallpaperURL, for: i, options: [:])
}
```

Comment: I want to change the background image of the virtual desktops (the ones you switch between with swipes). `NSScreen.screens()` only returns screens for each physical display.

Comment: the above script doesn't work for all virtual spaces

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Xcode 8.x:

```
if let screens = NSScreen.screens() {
    let newWallpaperURL = URL(/* ... */))
    for screen in screens {
        try? NSWorkspace.shared().setDesktopImageURL(newWallpaperURL, for: screen, options: [:])
    }
}
```

Unlike other solutions posted here this one will work in the current Xcode 8. `NSScreen.screens` is a *class var* in Xcode 9 (currently beta) but a *class func* in Xcode 8 which is why you need to put `.screens()` instead of `.screens`. Also, `screens` returns an optional so you need to safely unwrap it before passing it to the `for` loop.

Comment: I should probably clarify... by "space"/desktop I mean the virtual desktops you can navigate with three-four finger horizontal swipes.

`NSScreen.screens()` only returns screens for physical displays so I can't use it.

Comment: Maybe [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586289/setting-the-desktop-background-on-all-spaces-in-cocoa) will help you.